# Is feminism a discrimination-protected philosophical belief?

Tags: england-and-wales, discrimination, equality-act-2010

Is there any legal authority as to whether feminism is protected under the equality act as a characteristic of philosophical belief? If not one addressing the question directly, either with respect to feminism directly or any particular variety thereof, then do the authorities surrounding the question suggest that it would or wouldn't be protected?

Comment: Can you define the characteristics of feminism?

Comment: Could you give us examples of protections afforded to other beliefs under this act?

Comment: Feminism can refer to a wide range of beliefs ranging from equality to empowerment to outright transphobia. Give an actual example here.

Comment: Protected from what?  And what is different about "feminism" that might afford it any more or less protection than being an advocate for the humane treatment of kittens?

Comment: @hszmv Look up Maya Forstater for example who was dismissed for comments about transgender women on twitter.

Comment: @ComicSansStrikephim I don't see the relevance to my question directed at OP,

Comment: @ComicSansStrikephim Or, the OP is not... and wants some answers to the extent of the law.

Comment: Yes I think this sort of hostility and skepticism as well as arrogant opinion-spouting is completely contrary to the site policies.

Comment: @SeekingAnswers I apologise, that was overly cynical. The question could still do with more specific examples though.

Comment: I don't think it needs any further specificity. It decidedly allows for answers concerning either any particular form of feminism or feminism in general. It also intentionally doesn't restrict discrimination to that in the contexts of either employment or service consumption, partly because I don't believe the law draws any distinction as the qualifications of protected characteristics for legal protection stands independently of the context of application. If the question had been of ethical veganism then that question is clearly decided, there incidentally in the EAT.

Comment: I had vaguely in mind a belief that women are collectively oppressed in society but deliberately broadened it to include feminism of any description.